# iphone - Battery Utilization of each component

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios4

Is there any way, we can identify the battery utilization of each of the components/ processes running in an iPhone device ?

We can get the same details for android device through code. But, is the same possible for iPhone?

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean of apps that you have written, or for the whole device?

Comment: no, you can't do this with a non-private API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't access those information IN your app. The only possibility is with Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, Search "Energy Diagnostics" in http://gigaom.com/2010/08/04/apples-instruments-for-developers/ page.
OR
you can also find detail about "Energy Diagnostics" in XCode->orgniser->Documentation and search for "Energy Diagnostics" and you will find `Energy Usage Instrument` under header of `Tools Guides`. And It says:

*The Energy Usage instrument captures information about energy usage on a device since start up.*

*Platforms : iOS*
*Locations : Library pane (only appears when an iOS device is connected)*

Comment: Using Energy Diagnostics instrument, data we capture is not specific to our process. It only specifies which app is in foreground and background ...